# Difference between following phrase

Tags: relative-clauses, present-participles

> Many people living in that area are farmers

vs

> Many people **who** live in that area are farmers

And

> The man standing there is a driver

vs

> The man **who is** standing there is a driver

Comment: *Many people who living that area are farmers* is not grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

In the two pairs of the sentences

1.

> Many people who live in that area are farmers
>
> Many people living in that area are farmers

and

2.

> The man who is standing there is a driver
>
> The man standing there is a driver

the only difference is that the second sentence is a bit shorter, and this is the case of [reduced relative clauses](https://www.englishgrammar.org/reduced-relative-clauses/) when a participle is used instead of a relative pronoun--in your examples, it's ***who***--and the full verb.